# Nuxeo integration with spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

Can i use Nuxeo API Rest service to integrate it with spring boot application, and if so , does Nuxeo offers free services or just a trial period.

Answer (score 0):

Nuxeo has developed a java sdk, ready to use in your springboot app : https://github.com/nuxeo/nuxeo-java-client

Code example :

```
import org.nuxeo.client.NuxeoClient;
import org.nuxeo.client.objects.Document;
import org.nuxeo.client.objects.Documents;

NuxeoClient nuxeoClient = new NuxeoClient.Builder()
.url(url)
.authentication("Administrator","Administrator")
.connect();


// Fetch the root document
Document doc = nuxeoClient.operation(Operations.REPOSITORY_GET_DOCUMENT).param("value", "/").execute();

// Execute query
Documents docs = nuxeoClient.operation("Repository.Query")
                            .param("query", "SELECT * FROM Document")
                            .execute();
```